# How to Connect multiple servers using for Loop with iTerm2 Split

Tags: bash

I am trying to connect into multiple servers using for loop with iTerm2 split, but it appears not to connect to both servers instead it connects to last server server-2.domain.com

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

 old_server="server-1.domain.com  server-2.domain.com"

declare -a LM #declaring Array here
LM=($old_server)


for Host in "${LM[@]}"
do
     echo "Connecting to the server: ${Host}"

FUNCT="z2hs"
-- # Creating terminal splits
z2hs () {
    osascript &>/dev/null <<EOF
    tell application "iTerm2"
        activate
    
        tell current session of current tab of current window
            write text "ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${Host}"
            split horizontally with default profile
        end tell
        
        tell second session of current tab of current window
            write text "ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${Host}"
        end tell

    end tell
EOF
}

done
$FUNCT
```

I was wondering if someone could assist and see where i am getting wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the assignment:

```
old_server=server-1.domain.com  server-2.domain.com
```

the space means that only `old_server=server-1.domain.com` is treated as the assignment, the rest -- `server-2.domain.com` -- is treated as a command to apply that assignment to.

To get the entire string treated as a single item and assigned to the variable, you'd have to enclose it in quotes or escape the space. But don't do that; just set it directly as an array:

```
LM=(server-1.domain.com server-2.domain.com)
```

Storing the server list as a plain space-delimited string and then using word-splitting to turn it into an array gets you all the possible bugs that come from word-splitting, and the entire point of arrays is to avoid those possible bugs!

I'd also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names (i.e. not `LM` or `FUNCT`), because there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of those for something else it can cause problems.

Another problem is that the whole thing of setting `FUNCT` to "z2hs", declaring a function by that name, then using the variable  to call the function, is just an over-elaborate and confusing way to run a command. And the way you have it here won't even work right, because you run `$FUNCT` (which evaluates to "z2sh", which runs the function) just once, *after* the loop has ended, so it'll run with the `Host` set to what it was in the final iteration of the loop. To make this work, you'd move the assignment to `FUNCT` and definition of `z2hs` before the loop (rather than redefining them the exact same way every time through the loop), and put the command that runs the function *inside* the loop.

But that's still overcomplicated. I'd just run the `osascript` command directly, without the function or variable. Alternately, you could define the function *once* at the beginning of the script (not re-define it every time through the loop) and then run it directly (inside the loop) without putting its name in a variable first. To do that right, though, you'd want to pass the host name as a parameter to the function... eh, don't bother. Just use the `osascript` command directly.

Also, in the line:

```
-- # Creating terminal splits
```

the `--` will be treated as a command to run. `--` is a comment delimiter in AppleScript, not in shell.